# node:js:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am using fs-extra for moving my folders but I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

My code like below

```
var fse = require('fs-extra');
fse.move('/meteor/crm/uploads', '/meteor/crm/uploads/tmp', function (err) {
   if (err) return console.error(err)
   console.log("success!")
})
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Could you also provide this package and Meteor's versions?

Comment: Check `console.log(fse);` and `console.log(fse.move)`

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to run this server side or client side? I think that's the issue...

Answer (score 0):

try adding  `target: 'node',` to your webpack config